# Assuring stack pointer alignment using bitwise operators

Tags: stack, alignment, memory-alignment, stack-pointer

Assume I want to reserve `8 bytes` on the stack and I also want to make sure current `stack pointer` is 8 byte aligned. I have seen some codes that assure current `sp` is 8 bye aligned using this logic:

```
sp = sp & -8;
```

They `AND` it with the amount they are going to reserve on the stack (which of course is negative).

How does this logic work?

Answer (score 0):

It works because negative numbers are represented in two's complement, so `-8` is equivalent to `~7`, of which the 3 least significant bits are 0s and the rest are 1s. ANDing this with a value clears the 3 least significant bits, which obviously results in it being 8-byte aligned. By the way, this trick only works to align things to powers of 2. If you had some strange reason to align things to a 12-byte boundary, for example, `sp = sp & -12` would not work as intended.